# Book/Note recommendation for Dedekind criterion

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Recently I am working on polynomial rings and integral closure of discrete valuation rings. I am told to study Dedekind Criterion, but I need some book or notes on it. It will be beneficial if someone kindly helps me.

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: @StevenLandsburg yes, I have found some research papers but I couldn't understand. Also, sadly I don't have anyone with whom I can discuss about it.

Comment: Do you mean a [Dedekind domain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain)? If so this wiki link should have some references at the bottom to get you started.

Comment: @AlecRhea no not exactly Dedekind domain, it's Dedekind factorization criterion. I have found a research paper by S Khanduja, but I couldn't understand. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338745472_A_Note_on_Dedekind_Criterion